# Will ubuntu boot if the /boot partition is full?

Tags: boot, reboot

1. If the boot partition is 100% full will my system still be able to boot?

   I ask because I had a system go down and was unable to boot and I'm trying to find the root cause.  I'm suspecting its because `/boot` was 100% full but I don't understand why.
2. Are temp files written in `/boot` during the boot process?

Answer (score 1):

> If the boot partition is 100% full will my system still be able to boot?

Yes, you can be able to boot Ubuntu.

> Are temp files written in /boot during the boot process?

No temporary files were written to the `/boot` directroy while booting.

Answer (score 0):

The one problem that could prevent booting after /boot fills up is that you can end up with a new kernel installed in /boot, and run out of room to build the initrd to go with it.  Grub will automatically be updated and see the new kernel, and make it the default boot entry, but without the initrd, it won't work.  The solotion is simply to select the older kernel from the grub menu until you can clear out some free space in /boot and generate the new initrd ( and run `update-grub` ).