# Boot partition is full, running old kernel, new kernels "waiting" - safe to reboot?

Tags: kernel, boot-partition

This is not a duplicate as suggested above - for why, see the text below.

I have the strange situation that an "old" kernel is running (in fact it is the OLDEST):

`uname -r`

`> 4.13.0-43-generic`

Using a command to show available kernels I only see NEWER kernels(!):

```
sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'|awk '{ if ($1=="ii") print $2}'|grep -v `uname -r`
linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic
linux-image-4.15.0-24-generic
linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic
linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic
linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic
linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic
linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic
linux-image-extra-4.13.0-45-generic
```

It looks as if the system never rebooted to "get to the new kernels" - I see for example that in the root dir:

```
ls -al

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Sep 11 06:02 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-34-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Sep 11 06:02 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-33-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Sep 11 06:02 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-34-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Sep 11 06:02 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-33-generic
```

which kind of suggests this to me (I'm not an ubuntu guru)...

This is not a duplicate question but a **new** question because I have no **old** kernels to delete. Other answers detail deleting old kernels with version numbers **less** than the current kernel.

The running kernel is the oldest listed. I was worried about deleting kernels **newer** than the current kernel - between the current kernel and the newest and the kernel that was wanting to be installed - but blocked because of 100% full boot partition.

**All answers using "apt" do not work when the boot partition is 100% full** so please ignore them :)

From my original question:
So I'm tempted to reboot the machine. But is this dangerous - since the boot partition is 100% full.
"Normally" I'd delete old kernels etc. to free up space.
What's the best/safest way to proceed here?

I ask because it seems I "should" make some space (see [Will ubuntu boot if the /boot partition is full?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448668/will-ubuntu-boot-if-the-boot-partition-is-full))... but how in this particular case?

---

THIS IS HOW I SOLVED the problem:

In the end as `apt autoremove` etc. do not work in this situation I followed the hints given here:https://gist.github.com/ipbastola/2760cfc28be62a5ee10036851c654600
(See: *"Case II: Can't Use apt i.e. /boot is 100% full"*)

In my case I deleted a *newer* kernel by hand to release space in `/boot` in order to be able to proceed:

```
cd /boot
ls *4.13.0-45*
rm -rf *4.13.0-45*
df -h
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo update-grub
more grub/grub.cfg
reboot
```

`df -h` shows boot no longer 100% full
With `more grub/grub.cfg` you can check if the system is catering for the correct kernels (i.e. whether the `update grub` worked well)

Comment: Perhaps you could `sudo apt autoremove` which should remove older kernels, leave the current running kernel and the latest update.  This will free space, but not fix the booting into the old kernel problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands, in that order, one by one and check space every time.

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

then

```
sudo apt autoclean
```

and if not enough space yet run:

```
sudo apt clean
```

and

```
sudo update-grub
```

must work.

after reboot in **new kernel** confirm that the latest kernels are fully installed. by running:

```
uname -r
```

and

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

then run

```
sudo apt purge $(dpkg -l|egrep 'linux-image-[0-9]|linux-headers-[0-9]'|awk '{print $3,$2}'|grep -v `uname -r|cut -f1,2 -d"-"`|sort -nr|tail -n +4|awk '{ print $2}')
```

this will remove all old kernels except the one you are using and the latest one.

**Edit**

Note: You can run `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` to confirm that the latest kernels are fully installed, before all these commands.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the 'autoclean' step, since the following step ('clean') will delete all cached packages anyway.

Comment: That's why I said run the commands and check. Maybe you don't need to run 'clean'.

Comment: Right. I think you should clarify that in the answer.